# Proxmox error on vmbr0

Tags: proxmox

I can't access to my pve due to networking error:

```
error: vmbr0: bridge port enp5s1 does not exist
```

interface file:
[image]

networking status:
[image]

Note: The second bridge work ok, the modem and external ip address are reached from pve, the problem is with LAN bridged. Network card led indicator is on.

Comment: show `ip addr` output. Copy-paste, please. it's text information and there is no reason to photograph the screen.

Comment: Sorry, i can´t access to pve by network (by ssh for example) to copy files content. is vmbr0 net connected to LAN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `ip link show` to see known interfaces.

Is the interface there?  Perhaps it was renamed for some reason, or has a different name from the one you expect.

Running `dmesg |grep enp5s1` should show kernel messages relating to that interface name.

If nothing is shown in the `dmesg`, perhaps you're missing an appropriate driver.

Comment: Ohhhhh, exactly!!!. enp5s1 doesn't exist any more, now is named enp5s0. Renamed in interface file and now all is working like a sharm. but, why it happen??

Comment: Did the card get moved to a different PCIe slot?  Was the hardware changed in some way?  Usually the "enpXsY" is defined as en (ethernet) in p (position) X s (slot)  Y.  Sometimes the method of identifying the ethernet ports isn't 100% exact... but it's usually pretty close.  In my own environments... I often rename my adapters to something more logical... but that's just a personal preference.

Comment: you can also see other ethernet interfaces that look like "enoX" or  "ensX"  eno usually is an "onboard" port... and an "ens" is in a card slot...  ... in the case of enpXSY ... it's usually a multi-port card in a slot.

Comment: Well, It seems like someone from the area tried to fix it yesterday and ended up complicating the situation. I installed this server in 2021 and had never had problems.